# A complex metric

Tags: metric-spaces, complex-numbers

Given the following definition $d(z , w) = \begin{cases}0 & z=w \\ |z|+ |w| & z\neq w \end{cases}$

I have to prove that $d(z,w)= 0\Rightarrow  z = w$ Which is in part of checking that $d$ is a metric on $\Bbb C$

Given what I know about complex numbers , if $z= a+ bi$ and $w = c +di $ then $|z|= \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$  and  $ |w|= \sqrt{c^2+d^2}$  so $|z|+|w| >0 \forall z,w \in \Bbb C $  and so $d(x,y)=0$ only if $z=w$

I am worried that this is not an eloquent proof. I am prone to being pedantic on a daily basis though.

So if this is pedantic and a waste of your time I apologise

Comment: From (a little revision of) what you've written it should be easy to see that $|z|+|w| = 0 \iff z=w=0$.

Comment: If you really want to be sure you can use the notation $\rho e^{i\theta}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $d(z,w)=0$ and $z\not=w$. Then

$$0=d(z,w)=|z|+|w|$$

If the sum of two non-negative numbers is $0$, then they are both $0$. That is $|z|=|w|=0$, i.e. $z=w=0$. Contradiction.